# 'I was wondering if you would mind me [doing something] or [do something]'

Tags: grammar

I am confused：

> I was wondering if you would mind me **opening** the window.

or

> I was wondering if you would mind me **open** the window.

Which one is correct？

Answer (score 2):

Only the first sentence is grammatical, but the second one would be with a slight change:

> ✔ I was wondering if you would mind **me opening** the window.
>   ✔ I was wondering if you would mind **if I open** the window.

Note that in the second version, *opened* can also be used.

---

A more direct way of asking this is simply:

> Do you mind me opening the window?
>   Do you mind if I open the window?

Generally speaking, the last version is the most common.